# How can I separate a comma separated list by character count (<1000) but avoid splitting the words between commas?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I want to separate a large comma separated list into several smaller lists of less than 1000 characters without cutting off the actual words.

I've been using

```
=MID($A2,IF(COLUMN()-2=0,1,((COLUMN()-2)*1000)+1),1000)
```

However, with this formula, the words are cut off. For instance, a list would end with "train" and the following one would begin with "ing."

Here's an example spreadsheet for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HB82YQNjhpAwMJVCoTWjLKT9PHW32G0-FkAhK-lWiG8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You will want to use code to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Jayden. While I don't think this is a very appropriate problem for Excel functions (you should look into macros instead), it would probably help if you provide a more simple example with some sample inputs and expected/actual outputs (e.g. instead of using 1,000 as the limit, use 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your google doc, I think this is an XY problem. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Rather than helping you split a long string as per your question, it's far easier to help you join the list of words into a series of strings which are each less than 1000 characters. It works by giving each word a group number, ensuring the groups are less than 1000 characters when joined. Then join together the words in each group.

1. Insert 3 helpers columns after column A
2. B3: `=LEN(A3)+1` fill down (length of words plus comma)
3. C2: `0` (cumulative length start)
4. C3: `=IF(C2+B3<1000,C2+B3,B3)` fill down (cumulative length, resets at 1000)
5. D3: `=IF(OR(C3<C2,C2=0),D1+1,D1)` fill down (group counter)
6. E1, E2, E3...: `1`, `2`, `3` fill across
7. E2: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,OFFSET($A$3,MATCH(E$1,$D$3:$D$1002,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($D$3:$D$1002,E$1),1))` fill across
8. E3: `=LEN(E2)` fill across to check

In the final formula, you can replace the references to `E$1` with `COLUMN()-4` if you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I made one change in step 5 and everything works; instead of =IF(OR(C3<C2,C2=0),D1+1,D1), I set D2 as 0 and used =IF(OR(C3<C2,C2=0),D2+1,D2)

Comment: You're welcome. As this solved your problem, please mark my answer as correct using the geewn tick to show the question is resolved. Thanks.